# Прописать заголовки во вкладках SlidingTab

Tags: android, вкладки

Здравствуйте!
Есть простенький код. Все работает. Но у вкладок нет заголовков. Подскажите, как их прописать. Вот сам код:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
       /* mPager.setCurrentItem(1); */// выводим второй экран
        mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mPager);

    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new Fragment1();
                case 1:
                    return new Fragment2();
                case 2:
                    return new Fragment2();

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037887/how-can-i-put-titles-in-viewpager-using-fragments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в адаптер добавь

```
@Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.tab_1);
            case 1:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.tab_2);
            case 2:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.tab_3);
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }
```

mContext я просто в конструкторе адаптера передаю контект